# Isomorphism of meromorphic function fields implies Riemann surfaces are isomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

This is about from Forster, Lectures on Riemann Surfaces, Exercise 8.1.

The exercise is the following: ($\mathcal{M}(X)$ represents the field of meromorphic functions on $X$, and likewise for $Y$.)

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact Riemann surfaces such that $\mathcal{M}(X)$ and $\mathcal{M}(Y)$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}$ algebras. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

There's a hint which suggests representing $X$ and $Y$ as the Riemann surfaces of algebraic functions of the same polynomial $P$ from $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{P}^1)[T]$ and the fact (which is proved later) that the meromorphic functions separate points, over a compact Riemann surface.

To get started, it seems like I need a branched holomorphic covering map $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$. One candidate seems like using an arbitrary non constant element of $\mathcal{M}(X)$ and consider that as a surjective map into $\mathbb{P}^1$. However I'm not quite sure how to proceed. To that end I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint where to start.

(I am aware that something along these lines has already been asked here [If two meromorphic function fields on compact riemann surfaces isomorphic, then they are isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693008/if-two-meromorphic-function-fields-on-compact-riemann-surfaces-isomorphic-then), but it doesn't shed much light on how I might use the hint with whatever Forster has developed so far.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K:= \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ and $L_X := \mathcal{M}(X)$ and $L_Y :=\mathcal{M}(Y)$. Let $\Phi: L_X \to L_Y$ some $\mathbb{C}$-algebra isomorphism. As you said, take some non-constant function $f\in L_X$ (existence by the hint) and let $g:=\Phi(f)$. Then $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ and $g: Y \to \mathbb{P}^1$ are branched holomorphic coverings, finitely sheeted, because $X$ and $Y$ are compact.

Now, $f^*:K\to L_X$ is a finite algebraic field extension of degree $\leq n$, if $f$ is $n$-sheeted. By the primitive element theorem there is some $F_X \in L_X$ with $f^*K[F_X] = L_X$. Let $P \in K[T]$ be the minimal polynomial of $F_X$, i.e. $$\rho_X:K[T]/(P) \to L_X, q(T) \mapsto (f^*q)(F_X)$$
is an isomorphism, in particular $(f^*P)(F_X) = 0$. But it is also $g^*:K\to L_Y$ a finite algebraic field extension and $g^* = \Phi\circ f^*$, since per definition $g = \Phi(f)$. Set $F_Y := \Phi(F_X)$. Then $$\rho_Y:K[T]/(P) \to L_Y, q(T) \mapsto (g^*q)(F_Y)$$
is an isomorphism, because $\rho_Y = \Phi\circ\rho_X$, since $\Phi(\rho_X([q])) = \Phi((f^*q)(F_X)) = \Phi(f^*q)(\Phi(F_X)) = (g^*q)(F_Y) = \rho_Y([q])$. In particular $(g^*P)(F_Y) = 0$. This means, per definition, that $(X,f,F_X)$ and $(Y,g,F_Y)$ are algebraic functions defined by the irreducible polynomial $P\in K[T]$.

By uniqueness of the triples there is exactly one fiber-preserving biholomorphic mapping $\varphi: X \to Y$. This proves the claim.